# Convert Date to Long using query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called **User** which has a column **activityDate** of DataType DATETIME .

Now I have changed the DataType of column  **activityDate** form DateTime to Long .

So New values are inserted with long values.

How to convert the existing datas of the table without changing its pervious values to

long using query for MySql,SQL SERVER AND ORACLE.

I had no query found to change .

So guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: What is LONG ? there is no datatype called LONG in sql server. is this is something you are looking for ?? `SELECT CAST(DateTime_Column AS FLOAT)`

Comment: You have a `long` column and don't want to covert the existing data to `long`? How should that work?

Comment: In SQL SERVER numeric(19,0)  .I have used Long in my entity .

Comment: Have you tried something like `SELECT CAST(DateTime_Column AS NUMERIC(19,0))`  see if this gives you the required results

Comment: juergen d. I want to convert existing values to long as I am changing the datatype from dateTime to long

Comment: SELECT CAST(DateTime_Column AS NUMERIC(19,0))  this is not working

Comment: What do you want the converted number to represent?

Comment: converted number should represent the value of dateTime as Number(19,0) in case of oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use `FORMAT` to convert to anything you want

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '03/15/2014 16:35:44'

SELECT @date AS DateTimeColumn
       ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(19, 0), FORMAT(@date, 'yyyyMMddHHMMss')) AS DecimalColumn
```

In example I'm using `FORMAT` to strip to display just numeric parts of datetime and after that convert it to decimal.

For SQL Server 2008 R2 and before. You can use

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '03/15/2014 16:35:44'

SELECT @date AS DateTimeColumn
,CONVERT(DECIMAL(19, 0), REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @date, 120), '-', ''), ' ', ''),':', '')) AS DecimalFromVarchar
```

First convert to varchar with a specific style that you want and than just remove non numeric characters and after that convert to decimal.

`FORMAT` - [syntax here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) 
`CONVERT` - [syntax here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2 and format is not supported .

Comment: in that case just use the `CONVERT` and multiple replace.